# This expression has type Sast.var_decl but an expression was expected of type Ast.var_decl (write a compile with Ocaml )

Tags: ocaml

I am writing a small compiler using Ocaml. I want to typecheck Ast and then put into Sast.

But I always get error as follows:

```
  File "typecheck_debug.ml", line 93, characters 28-35:
    Error: This expression has type Sast.var_decl
           but an expression was expected of type Ast.var_decl
```

The code is:

```
    let rec trans_lval env = function
          Ast.Id(n) -> let vdecl = (find_variable env.scope n) in
                       Sast.Id(vdecl), vdecl.vvtype 

    ocamllex scanner.mll
    ocamlyacc parser.mly
    ocamlc -c ast.mli
    ocamlc -c parser.mli
    ocamlc -c scanner.ml
    ocamlc -c parser.ml
    ocamlc -c sast.mli
    ocamlc -c typecheck_debug.ml
```

I do not understand why. Is there something wrong with my project process?

Comment: It would help to see relevant sections of ast.mli and sast.mli.

Comment: possible relevant project: https://github.com/oliverhu/pltdone

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from only that little bit of code, but it sounds like `Sast.Id` expects a value of type `Sast.var_decl` as its argument, but `find_variable` produces a value of type `Ast.var_decl`, so that's the type of `vdecl`.

I'm assuming here that line 93, characters 28-35 is `(vdecl)`. If that is not the case, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the problem is not there, but in another arm of the function `trans_lval` (which you don't show, but there has to be others, your ast can't only be made of `Id`s). A simple way of checking which part(s) of your code is the culprit consists in:

1. add explicit type annotations to your function, for instance:

   ```
   let rec trans_lval : Ast.lval -> Sast.lval = function
      (*  code follows *)
   ```

   (This is probably wrong, I obviously cannot tell the real type of your function from the information you gave).
2. commenting out bits of your function code, until the error disappears.
   When it happens, you know that a conflict exists at least in the last bit of code you've commented out. You may try then to solve that issue.
3. After that uncomment the other commented bits, and solve any other issue that appears in the process.